# Training and testing set for speech recognition

Tags: speech-recognition, data-request

I am the moment looking for a dataset similar to the caltech 101, but in this case for different phrases, words and so on... In general just words.

Does someone know if such dataset exist, or I have to create it myself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a huge academic data set repository in http://academictorrents.com/
 give it try, you might find something. Also, there is commeresial data base of Penn state university,here: https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2011S08.

Comment: A small tip here is that search within restricted domain of university website, meaning google like this:
>Dataset  site:*.edu
OR
>Dataset site:* .ac.*

Answer (score 0):

There are many open source datasets for speech available for free. You can find most at http://www.openslr.org

Beside that you can check http://voxforge.org